# Get data from multiple inner joins

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have following tables.

### Table: **PollingBooth**  PBId is primary key.

```
PBID  | PBName |pdivID      
-----------------------
1     | Jaya PB | 1

2     | SP PB   | 1
```

Table: PollingDivision - pdID is primary key.

```
----------------

pdID  |pdName
------------------
1     | Homagama 

2     | Maharagama
```

Table:ElectionOfficial -EoId is primary key.

```
----------------
EoID   |EoName
---------------
1      | Sam

2      | Ram

3      | Feston
```

Table: Election-  elecID is primary key.

```
--------------------------------------
elecID    | ElecName
--------------------------------------
1         | Presidential Election 2013

2         | General Election 2014
```

Table: PollingBoothElection-  Both pbID and elecID columns forms a primary key

```
--------------------------------
pbID   | elecID |numofEOs
--------------------------------
1      | 1      | 2

2      | 1      | 3
```

Table: PollingBoothElectionOfficial. All three columns together a combined primary key.

```
----------------------------------

pbID   | elecID   | eOfficialID 
----------------------------------

1      | 1        |1

1      | 1        |2
```

I want to select all the PollingBooth names of a particular PollingDivision in which count of the eoID for each PollingBooth for a particular election is less than the allowed number of election officials for a particular election.

In other words I want to select all the PollingBooth Names in which count of all eOfficialID in PollingBoothElectionofficial table for a given pbID and an elecID is less than the value of numberofEOs of PollingBoothElection for the same eleID and the pbID and I want to do this for all the polling booths of a particular PollingDivision.

Here's what I tried.

```
   SELECT PB.PBName, COUNT(PBEO.eOfficialID)
   FROM PollingBoothElection PBE
   INNER JOIN PollingBooth PB ON PBE.pbID=PB.PBID
   INNER JOIN PollingDivision PD ON PB.pdivID=PD.pdID
   INNER JOIN PollingBoothElectionOfficial PBEO ON PBE.elecID=PBEO.elecID 
   AND PBE.pbID=PBEO.pboothID
   WHERE PBE.elecID=1 AND PD.pdName='Homagama' AND PBE.numOfEO>(SELECT COUNT(PBEO.eOfficialID))
   GROUP BY PB.PBName;
```

But this says that i can't include aggregate function in where clause. So how can I check count of each polling booth's election officials for a particular election in PollingBoothElectionOfficial table is not greater than the number of allowed election officials given in the PollingBoothElection table.

Is there a way that I can achieve this with IF ELSE Statements?

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please learn to format your posts after 13 ones.

Comment: Not Both pbID and elecID are primary keys, it's them together to form a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the error you cannot use `aggregate` function in `where` clause to filter the result set.

Move that condition from `Where clause` to `Having Clause` which is used to search condition for a `group` or an `aggregate`

```
SELECT PB.PBName,
       Count(PBEO.eOfficialID)
FROM   PollingBoothElection PBE
       INNER JOIN PollingBooth PB
               ON PBE.pbID = PB.PBID
       INNER JOIN PollingDivision PD
               ON PB.pdivID = PD.pdID
       INNER JOIN PollingBoothElectionOfficial PBEO
               ON PBE.elecID = PBEO.elecID
                  AND PBE.pbID = PBEO.pboothID
WHERE  PBE.elecID = 1
       AND PD.pdName = 'Homagama'
GROUP  BY PB.PBName,PBE.numOfEO
HAVING Count(PBEO.eOfficialID) < PBE.numOfEO
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the above solution resolve your error but the join and the conditions you are using are not proper, and the method count is used twice which we can avoid, and 'AND' condition between the inner join is not necessary(you can put it in where clause). Also you are not checking the lkup table to join conditions may come, in which data deleted from lkup table which could give wrong output. My advice for the joins and conditions are, check this out :)

```
SELECT 
    PB.PBName AS BoothName,
    Count(PBEO.eOfficialID) AS EoTotalCount
FROM
    PollingBooth PB
    INNER JOIN pollingDivision pdiv ON pdiv.pdID = pb.pdivID
    INNER JOIN pollingBothElection pbelec ON pbelec.pbID = pb.pbID
    INNER JOIN Election election ON election.elecID = pbelec.elecID
    INNER JOIN PollingBoothElectionOfficial pBothElecO ON pBothElecO.pbID = PB.PBID
    INNER JOIN ElectionOfficial eo ON eo.EoID = pBothElecO.eOfficialID
WHERE
    pbelec.elecID = 1
    AND pdiv.pdID = 1
GROUP BY
    pb.pbID,
    pbelec.numOfEO
HAVING 
    EoTotalCount < pbelec.numOfEO
```